# Concatenate DISTINCT string after a group BY in Python-Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

When grouping a Polars dataframe in Python, how do you concatenate string values from a single column across rows within each group?

For example, given the following DataFrame:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"],
        "col2": ["val1", "val2", "val1", "val3", "val3"]
    }
)
```

Original df:

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ a    ┆ val1 │
│ b    ┆ val2 │
│ a    ┆ val1 │
│ b    ┆ val3 │
│ c    ┆ val3 │
└──────┴──────┘
```

I want to run a groupby operation, like:

```
df.groupby("col1").agg(
    pl.col("col2").str.concat_distinct(",")
)
```

The expected output is:

```
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2_g    │
│ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str       │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ val1      │
│ b    ┆ val2,val3 │
│ c    ┆ val3      │
└──────┴───────────┘
```

I see the question here: [In a Polars groupby aggregation, how do you concatenate string values in each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76223362/in-a-polars-groupby-aggregation-how-do-you-concatenate-string-values-in-each-gr)

But the answers doesn't focus on unique value in the concat.

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`unique()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.unique.html#polars.Expr.unique) and [`str.concat()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.concat.html#polars.Expr.str.concat) for that

```
df = df.group_by("col1").agg(
    pl.col("col2").unique().str.concat(",")
)
print(df)
```

result

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2      │
│ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str       │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│ c    ┆ val3      │
│ a    ┆ val1      │
│ b    ┆ val2,val3 │
└──────┴───────────┘
```

also, please be aware that [`groupby()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby.html) is deprecated so it's better to use [`group_by()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by.html#polars.DataFrame.group_by) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate string values from a single column across rows within each group in a Polars DataFrame in Python, you can use the agg function with pl.col to specify the column . Here's the code

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
 {
    "col1": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"],
    "col2": ["val1", "val2", "val1", "val3", "val3"]
 }
)

df=df.groupby("col1").agg(
 col2_g=pl.col("col2").apply(
    lambda group: ",".join(group.unique()),return_dtype=pl.datatypes.Utf8
  )
)

print(df)
```

Comment: My issue is the "concat_distinct" . I don't find a way to create the function "concat_distinct". I already try the "agg", it's work to concatenate all string but it's not handle the duplicated values

Comment: you can use the following approach:

df.groupby("col1").agg(
    col2_g = pl.col("col2").distinct().str.join(",")
)

This will produce the expected output with unique concatenated values within each group

Comment: the function distinct doesn't work in the agg...

Comment: @Ouakrat, yes check the updated answer should work